# Get original image region pixel coordinates using wpf canvas

Tags: .net, wpf, canvas

I did application with WPF Image control, and I have image control in Canvas. Also I did draw rectangle on canvas with the help of "Using a rectangle to create a search region on an image" blogs.

And now I have Rectangle size related to canvas element.

Now my need is how to calculate image region coordinates of above rectangle size